# How do I get Python's pprint to return a string instead of printing?

Tags: python, pretty-print, pprint

In other words, what's the sprintf equivalent for `pprint`?

Answer (score 382, accepted):

The [pprint](http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html) module has a function named [pformat](http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html#pprint.pformat), for just that purpose.

From the documentation:

> Return the formatted representation of object as a string. indent,
> width and depth will be passed to the PrettyPrinter constructor as
> formatting parameters.

Example:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> people = [
...     {"first": "Brian", "last": "Kernighan"}, 
...     {"first": "Dennis", "last": "Richie"},
... ]
>>> pprint.pformat(people, indent=4)
"[   {   'first': 'Brian', 'last': 'Kernighan'},\n    {   'first': 'Dennis', 'last': 'Richie'}]"
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, it was really helpful. As a sidenote for 2021, in many contexts it is useful to add `sort_dicts=False` to the arguments of  `pprint.pformat`, because this preserves the original order of dictionaries. (I think this option is only valid with the newer versions of Python).

Comment: `sort_dicts` was implemented in python 3.8

Answer (score 21):

Assuming you really do mean `pprint` from the [pretty-print library](http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html), then you want
the `pprint.pformat` function.

If you just mean  `print`, then you want `str()`

Answer (score 19):

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pformat({'key1':'val1', 'key2':[1,2]})
"{'key1': 'val1', 'key2': [1, 2]}"
>>>
```

Answer (score 17):

Are you looking for `pprint.pformat`?

Answer (score 15):

Something like this:

```
import pprint, StringIO

s = StringIO.StringIO()
pprint.pprint(some_object, s)
print s.getvalue() # displays the string
```

Comment: technically the only "correct" answer considering only the title